# Use d.ts files without TypeScript (instead of JSDoc)

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings, jsdoc

I'm working on a JavaScript project using babel. I've used .d.ts files to define types for each .js file / class just for code completion instead of JSDoc.

This works fine when importing the Ability.js files within an other class. All the type definitions work for both variables and functions, and I can look into the properties of the 'Move' class. But when working in the Ability.js file, VSCode does not recognize any of the types.

I cannot find anything about it and I have tried adding `/// <reference path="./Ability.d.ts" />` as well. Is it simply not possible to use d.ts files like this instead of JSDocs?

Example;

```
// Ability.js
import Move from 'models/Move'
export default class Ability {
    constructor (ability) {
        this.name = ability.name
        this.move = ability.move
    }
    getMove () {
        return this.move
    }
}

// Ability.d.ts
import Move from 'models/Move'
export default class Ability {
    constructor (ability: Object);
    public name: string;
    public move: Move;
    public getMove: () => Move;
}
```

Comment: I've been encountering the same thing and haven't found a solution. Though if you `import Ability from './Ability';` in another file, you'll get intellisense for `Ability` in that file.